# phrase choice: for better and worse vs. for better or worse

Tags: phrase-meaning

I know the phrase "for better or worse," but recnetly, I've seen "for better AND worse." Is there any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The known phrase is "for better *or* (for) worse". The second 'for' is sometimes omitted in modern quotations.

The idiom can be found in the *Book of Common Prayer* of 1549, meaning the language is somewhat archaic; however the texts in the book are still used in some traditional church services including traditional *wedding vows* which is why the idiom is still widely known and used. In these vows, the bride and groom promise to stay together "for better or for worse", meaning in good times or bad.

"For better *and* for worse" also makes sense, but it isn't the original idiom. I would imagine that some people say it either in error, or because they perceive the meaning to be the same.

As the most common use of the expression is speculative - forward-looking - I feel it makes more sense to say "or". Saying that you promise to stay faithful to your spouse in good times *and* bad suggests that you definitely will have both good and good times, which may well be true but perhaps isn't so romantic. Saying "for better *or* worse" is a better acknowledgement that the future is unknown, but you will stick to your vows no matter what.